# ClickSeries Event

Tags: teechart

I am evaluating Teechart 4.1.2012.2287 and I have a problem with the Series.ClickSeries event.

My project is written in VS2010, using VB.Net and framework 4.0.
The ClickSeries event seems to work fine if there are a limited number of points in the series, say 100, but throws an exception if you have more data, say 1000 points.

This even happens on a new windows form project with just a single TChart placed on the form.

I have also found that the Chart header font, and custom axis fonts sometimes get changed after a Tchart1.update().

Do you have a fix for these problems?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this here using a line series with 10000 random points. Could you please send a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here at http://www.steema.net/upload/? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have uploaded a simple project called ClickSeries Error.
This is  a windows form project with one form that contains a TChart control.
The initialisation routine adds a single fastline series, and populates it using fillsampledata.

On my computer if the number of fill points is set to say 1000 I get an exception when I click on the chart. 100 or below points and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your project. I can reproduce your problem using a FastLine but no using a Line. I have added it in bug list report with number [TF02016143]. We will try to fix it for next maintenance releases of TeeChartFor.Net

Thanks,

Best regards,